# RangeError (length): Invalid value: Only valid value is 0: 1. Error thrown Instance of 'ErrorDescription'

Tags: flutter, dart, crashlytics

We just released our app. And are seeing these crashes in production. But the stacktrace is not leading me somewhere usefull.

RangeError (length): Invalid value: Only valid value is 0: 1. Error thrown Instance of 'ErrorDescription

```
Non-fatal Exception: FlutterError
0  ???                            0x0 first (dart:core)
1  ???                            0x0 assembleSemanticsNode + 436 (paragraph.dart:436)
2  ???                            0x0 compileChildren + 3717 (object.dart:3717)
3  ???                            0x0 compileChildren + 3709 (object.dart:3709)
4  ???                            0x0 compileChildren + 3709 (object.dart:3709)
5  ???                            0x0 compileChildren + 3709 (object.dart:3709)
6  ???                            0x0 compileChildren + 3709 (object.dart:3709)
7  ???                            0x0 compileChildren + 3709 (object.dart:3709)
8  ???                            0x0 compileChildren + 3709 (object.dart:3709)
9  ???                            0x0 compileChildren + 3709 (object.dart:3709)
10 ???                            0x0 compileChildren + 3663 (object.dart:3663)
11 ???                            0x0 compileChildren + 3709 (object.dart:3709)
12 ???                            0x0 compileChildren + 3587 (object.dart:3587)
13 ???                            0x0 _updateSemantics + 2631 (object.dart:2631)
14 ???                            0x0 flushSemantics + 1081 (object.dart:1081)
15 ???                            0x0 drawFrame + 441 (binding.dart:441)
16 ???                            0x0 drawFrame + 914 (binding.dart:914)
17 ???                            0x0 _handlePersistentFrameCallback + 302 (binding.dart:302)
18 ???                            0x0 _invokeFrameCallback + 1117 (binding.dart:1117)
19 ???                            0x0 handleDrawFrame + 1055 (binding.dart:1055)
20 ???                            0x0 _handleDrawFrame + 971 (binding.dart:971)
```

### Steps to Reproduce

I can't reproduce the issue. I see these crashes in firebase.

Logs

```
No problems with the analyzer
```

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.6, on Mac OS X 10.15.7 19H114 darwin-x64, locale en-BE)
    • Flutter version 1.22.6 at /Users/vanlooverenkoen/fvm/versions/stable
    • Framework revision 9b2d32b605 (5 weeks ago), 2021-01-22 14:36:39 -0800
    • Engine revision 2f0af37152
    • Dart version 2.10.5
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             [✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
    • Android SDK at /Users/vanlooverenkoen/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.2
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 12.0.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 12.0.1, Build version 12A7300
    • CocoaPods version 1.10.0

[!] Android Studio (version 4.1)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    ✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    ✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495)

[!] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2020.3)
    • IntelliJ at /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app
    ✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    ✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
    • For information about installing plugins, see
      https://flutter.dev/intellij-setup/#installing-the-plugins

[!] VS Code (version 1.53.2)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    ✗ Flutter extension not installed; install from
      https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.flutter
```

Comment: I think, you should share the code that is causing the error so that, we can help you better.

Comment: That's the problem I have no idea where this error is caused. I got this error in firebase, production.

Comment: Maybe in a ListView or something. Where you have to give a length parameter as input.

Comment: I was thinking maybe it has something todo with an empty of null text? Because of the paragraph.dart file. But I can't find anything there as well

Comment: Well, what you can do is instead of sharing the entire code, you comment some part of the code and test your app. That way also, you can find the error causing Widget. Then, you can share it here for us to determine the reason.

Comment: Yeah I think that is the next thing that I will do I was hoping that maybe somebody already had the same problem and could point me in a specific direction. I guess I will have to completely debug our app :D

Comment: thanks already for your support

Comment: I was able to find this issue: I saw that the issue was happening for almost every user at the launch of our app. after that the error never happend again. So I tested the registration flow and I found a bug in our choose password screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In our case we had a rich text with a clickable textspan.

This was causing an issue.

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/69787
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/51936

update to flutter 2.0.0 for a potential fix

workaround for pre flutter 2.0.0:

```
ExcludeSemantics(
  excluding: true,
  child: RichText( ... ),
),
```