# RangeError (length): Invalid value: Only valid value is 0: 1

Tags: flutter, dart

I am getting this error for some iOS users, a small percentage, on registration they cannot complete registration on their device and need to use an alternative device to do so.

Where does RangeError (length) come from?

The issue is mentioned  here but was closed

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/125912

It was also opened here but this does not seem relevant
[RangeError (length): Invalid value: Only valid value is 0: 1. Error thrown Instance of 'ErrorDescription'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66351424/rangeerror-length-invalid-value-only-valid-value-is-0-1-error-thrown-insta)

The app uses Flutter 3.10.6

The app crashes somewhere in this code
on receiving an empty json inside result {}

```
Map<String, dynamic> jsonMap = jsonDecode(result);

final MyModel myModel =
   jsonMap.isEmpty ? MyModel.empty() : MyModel.fromJson(jsonMap)

 factory MyModel.empty() {
    return MyModel(
      active: false,
      cycleLength: null,
      dateOfBirth: null,
      temperatureScale: TemperatureScale.defaultValue.key,
      irregularMode: false,
      savedAt: null,
      onBoardingStartDate: DateTime.now().toIso8601String(),
      conditions: ConditionModel.empty(),
    );
  }

  factory ConditionModel.empty() {
    return ConditionModel({});
  }

  static bool isUSA = Intl.systemLocale.split('_')[1].toUpperCase() == 'US' ||
      Platform.localeName.split('_').length == 1;

  static final TemperatureScaleEnum defaultValue = isUSA
      ? TemperatureScaleEnum.fahrenheit
      : TemperatureScaleEnum.celsius;
```

I think the isUSA code is possibly a bug and can be improved on but not sure if that is the cause of this error

Comment: range error is thrown when you try access an element( typically in a `List` or `String` ) with an index that doesn’t  exist. Like say access 3rd element when length of list is 2

Comment: Yes but that is (index) and not (length)

Comment: its probably this line : `Intl.systemLocale.split('_')[1].toUpperCase()`

Comment: Agreed  I think that is the most likely. It is not good code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems prone to exactly the error you describe:

```
 Intl.systemLocale.split('_')[1].toUpperCase() == 'US'
```

People with a locale with no underscore in it will get the error you describe.

Why not just

```
Intl.systemLocale.toUpperCase().endsWith('_US')
```

Comment: How can I manage to get my device to have no locale? 
Will changing the language to for example English UK and then back to English US fix the issue? Asking for customer support reasons

I am not able to reproduce the exact error but het the RangeError Index error